# Use Angular App in Angular Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page that functions like a layout in MVC.NET. It contains an angular app that loads an HTML page named "AngularJSON.html" using `templateUrl`. AngularJSON.html contains an angular app that performs `$http.get()` and populates a table with the results.

If I load "AngularJSON.html" into a browser by itself, it performs the GET and populates the table correctly. If I load the layout page into a browser, the static elements of AngularJSON.html display correctly, but the table, which uses `ng-repeat` does not display at all.

How can I get the template page to display correctly within the layout?

**ReportableStocksLayout.html** - Layout page.

```
    <script>
        var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);
        mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.

            when('/viewStocks', {
                templateUrl: 'AngularJSON.html',
                controller: 'viewStocksController'
            }).

            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/viewStocks'
            });
        }]);

        mainApp.controller('viewStocksController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Add Cows";
        });

    </script>
```

The templateURL page "AngularJSON.html" contains an angular app that performs `$http.get` and populates a table with the results.

**AngularJSON.html** -JavaScript

```
<script>
    var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);

    app2.controller('StocksController', function ($scope, $http) {
        // When the page loads...
        // Load myData with REST GET
        $http.get("http://stocquer.com/stocQuerWebAPI/api/Ticker/").then(function (response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data;
        });
    });

</script>
```

**AngularJSON.html** -HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="StocksController">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Symbol
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
            <td>
                {{ x.Ticker }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" ng-click='EditTicker(x.Ticker)'>Edit</a> |
                <a href="#" ng-click='DetailsTicker(x.Ticker)'>Details</a> |
                <a href="#" ng-click='DeleteTicker(x.Ticker)'>Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <hr />
</div>
```

Maybe I have encountered the bootstrapping problem. Since my angular apps are in two separate HTML files, I had hoped to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.**

So using routing doesn't make much sense (?) because you have to make nested and that will not work.

However if you are not nesting AngularJS ng-app then you have to do this:
To run multiple applications in one HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using `angular.bootstrap()` [Link to documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap).

So I guess you would do like this:

```
<div id="myApp2" ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="StocksController">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Symbol
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
            <td>
                {{ x.Ticker }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" ng-click='EditTicker(x.Ticker)'>Edit</a> |
                <a href="#" ng-click='DetailsTicker(x.Ticker)'>Details</a> |
                <a href="#" ng-click='DeleteTicker(x.Ticker)'>Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
</div>
```

And then in JS

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("myApp2"), ['myApp2']);
```